# When fadeToggle() fades out the element forever?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
  function blink(el) {
    el.fadeToggle("500", blink);
  }

$("body").on('click', '.l_acceptedanswer', function(e) {
    var $el = $(this).find('.fa-check');
  blink($el);
 
});
```

```css
.fa-check {
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check.checked {
    color: #44b449;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<a class='l_acceptedanswer'>
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<a class='l_acceptedanswer'>
    <i class="fa fa-check checked" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<a class='l_acceptedanswer'>
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

As you see, when I click on the one of those checked-icons, it will be hidden. Why? I expect it blinks forever. What's wrong?

Comment: *"As you see,"* - What I see when I click it is an error in the console.

Comment: @nnnnnn When you click on a checked-icon what happens? It will be removed, why? I want to fade it in again and out and in and out ... In other word I want to make it winking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide `blink` as the callback for `fadeToggle()`, it calls it without your element as an argument. That's why you're getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fadeToggle' of undefined` - because `el` is `undefined`.

One way to fix that is as follows.

**EDIT:** In a comment, @stack mentioned not being able to set a shorter delay for faster blinking. When specifying a number of milliseconds the first argument to `.fadeToggle()` needs to be a number, not a string. So change `"500"` (string) to `100` (number).

```js
function blink(el) {
  el.fadeToggle(100, function() {
    blink(el)
  });
}

$("body").on('click', '.l_acceptedanswer', function(e) {
  var $el = $(this).find('.fa-check');
  blink($el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<a class='l_acceptedanswer'>
  <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<a class='l_acceptedanswer'>
  <i class="fa fa-check checked" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<a class='l_acceptedanswer'>
  <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Note: You should've seen this error in the console - even if you didn't look at your browser's console, the Stack Overflow code snippet console shows it to you pretty clearly.

Comment: I see. thank you .. upvote. Just one thing, how can I make blinking faster? When I set it `0` it still is slow `el.fadeToggle("0", function() {`. Why?

Comment: You need to pass a number, not a string, so remove the quotes. Using 0 is way too fast, but maybe try `el.fadeToggle(100, function()...`

Comment: As I said, 0 is too fast - even if it "worked" you wouldn't see anything but a blur if it hides and shows with no delay. It works with 100: https://jsfiddle.net/dcaqkpkp/3/ - I assume that's the "blinking" effect you want. (I haven't looked into it, but I suspect maybe jQuery doesn't do a 0 delay asynchronously so then you get a stack overflow.)